# cordova fails to add plugin correctly

Tags: android, cordova

Every time I add a plugin, I get the following message:

```
(node:27816) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at getJson (C:\Users\bdavis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\util\metadata.js:29:31)
    at Object.exports.get_fetch_metadata (C:\Users\bdavis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\util\metadata.js:41:24)
    at C:\Users\bdavis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\platform\addHelper.js:343:48
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\bdavis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\bdavis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\bdavis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
    at C:\Users\bdavis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:810:14
    at flush (C:\Users\bdavis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
(node:27816) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:27816) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

It actually does install the plugin, but does not create cordova_plugins.js. When I try removing and readding the platform, it also works up until the cordova_plugins.js step, so I think it is related to creating or updating that file. The project will build and run fine for iOS; it will build for Android, and run, but has runtime errors because it cannot load the plugins.

Tried:

- npm reinstall everythingUnderTheSun
- Close and reopen visual studio
- complaining

I was thinking of trying crying next, but I don't know that will be successful. Figured I may have more luck here.

Versions:

- node 10.11
- npm 6.4.1
- cordova 8.0.0
- cordova-android 6.4.0

Update 9/27 14:20 EST:
So plugins/android.json is missing. I copied it from elsewhere on my hard drive and tried doing a platform add/remove and it gave a different error (copied below) following which, android.json is gone from the plugins directory again.

```
$ cordova platform add android
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~7.0.0
(node:11704) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@~7.0.0
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 4294963248 Error output:
```

Comment: Have you checked if any of plugin json files have been corrupted? plugins > fetch.json / android.json. Oh and try running with --verbose flag, perhaps it could help locating the problem.

Comment: @somerandomusername Thanks for the direction. Updated post. I'll keep looking into it too.

Comment: I dunno if anyone can ever figure this out but I ended up obliterating the project and starting over, with a backup from a while ago... I so love Cordova so very much maybe even all my heart. =(